# What is the general term of this recursive sequence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This real sequence is defied by recursion but I could not find the general term of it. (Really, I have the general term, but I don't know how it's been found.)
Suppose $\{ x_n\}$ is a real sequence which $x_1=\frac{1}{3}$ and for any $n>1$ the terms defined recursively as below:
$$x_{2n}=\frac{1}{3}x_{2n-1}$$
$$x_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{3}+x_{2n}$$
What is the general term of this sequence?

Comment: The general terms are:

$$x_{2n}=\frac{1}{3^2}\Sigma^{n-1}_{k=0}\frac{1}{3^k}$$
$$x_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{3}\Sigma^{n}_{k=0}\frac{1}{3^k}$$

I tried with generating functions, but it seems not be a good choice, because I finally had to divide two complicated power series. maybe my approach to this problem is not correct.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let $a_n = x_{2n-1}$ and $b_n = x_{2n}$. Use the recursion for $x_n$ to find recursions for $a_n$ resp. $b_n$. Solve $a_n$ and $b_n$ by generating functions or otherwise. Combine.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, but your comment is too general!
My trouble exactly is when I used Generating functions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It never hurts to gather some data: the first few terms are

$$\frac13,\frac19,\frac49,\frac4{27},\frac{13}{27},\frac{13}{81},\frac{40}{81},\frac{40}{243},\frac{121}{243}\;.$$

Look at the terms with odd indices: $$\frac13,\frac49,\frac{13}{27},\frac{40}{81},\frac{121}{243}\;.$$ It's pretty apparent that in each case the denominator is one more than twice the numerator. The denominator of $x_{2n-1}$ is evidently $3^n$, and the numerator seems to be $\frac12(3^n-1)$, so we conjecture that

$$x_{2n-1}=\frac{3^n-1}{2\cdot3^n}=\frac12-\frac1{2\cdot3^n}$$

and hence $$x_{2n}=\frac13\left(\frac12-\frac1{2\cdot3^n}\right)=\frac16-\frac1{2\cdot3^{n+1}}\;.$$

Once you make this conjecture, proving it by induction on $n$ is straightforward.

Another approach is to observe that we can write $x_{2n-1}=\frac{a_n}{3^n}$ for some positive integer $a_n$, in which case $x_{2n}=\frac{a_n}{3^{n+1}}$. Now

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{3^{n+1}}=x_{2n+1}=\frac13+x_{2n}=\frac13+\frac{a_n}{3^{n+1}}=\frac{a_n+3^n}{3^{n+1}}\;,$$

so $a_{n+1}=a_n+3^n$. It follows easily that $$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}3^k=\frac{3^n-1}2\;,$$

which is exactly what we conjectured just from the numerical data.

Comment: Thank you Brian. your answer is correct, but have you any offer for the mentioned general terms?

Comment: @RR: See the addition that I just made; it essentially gives you the one for $x_{2n-1}$, and from that the one for $x_{2n}$ is immediate.

Comment: You right, thank you. all of my mistake was having answer and taking no effort on the general term i have!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RR: You're welcome.